# Any way to customize the tooltip background color in reference window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image: tooltip background]

Cannot find a way to customize this tooltip's color.
Visual Studio 2022 v17.8.5

Comment: I have been battling this for awhile now.  Hope someone can answer you.